# Gettig text out of SAP confirmation Box with vba

Tags: excel, vba, messagebox, sap-gui

I'm automating a process with VBA, and I'm using SAP GUI Scripting to do so.

The macro is to create dispute cases and it works fine but I want to know if it's possible to extract a text from a confirmation box when the case is duplicated.

[image]

I have the code to get the text from a information box but doesn't work with this window.

```
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/txtMESSTXT1").Text
```

This is the part of the code where I'm trying to get the text:

> If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4LE4.jpg)" Then
> 'copy text from pop up
> rn(I, 11) = session.findById("wnd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4LE4.jpg)").Text 'This only returns the name of the box.

Comment: In the past I've been able to use the SAP Scripting Tracker [https://tracker.stschnell.de/] to figure out objects. Maybe this can help?

Comment: Maybe like this `session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtSPOP-TEXTLINE1").Text` ? 
Have you tried to use script recorder and click text field to see what is saved in script?

Comment: "wnd1" is incorrect. should be wnd[1]. Also are you sure its 1? from my experince try 2. this may work..